# Как из массива получить конкретные данные?

Tags: php

Мой массив

```
array(2) {
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(17) "Example COOL NICE"
    ["name"]=>
    string(13) "Bilal Shaheen"
    ["show_info"]=>
    NULL
  }
  ["_multiwidget"]=>
  int(1)
}
```

Пытаюсь получить значения title и name, 2 часа вожусь, не получается.
Пожалуйста, помогите получить значения в переменные $title и $name

Comment: $title = $array[2]['title'] и $name = $array[2]['name'] два часа?

Comment: Больше 2 часов ) Ошибку выдает Notice: Undefined variable: array in

Comment: Вместо `$array` поставьте переменную с вашим массивом. И откройте уже руководство по php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo $arr['2']['title']; 
echo $arr['2']['name'];
```

где `$arr` Вам массив

Comment: `$title = $array[2]['title'];
$name = $array[2]['name'];
echo $title; 
echo $name;` Появляется ошибка Notice: Undefined variable: array in

Comment: У вас не определена переменная `$array`